# overridden three20 TTDefaultStyleSheet style not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20, subclassing

i recently got three20 integrated into my app and am trying to override the default toolbar color in TTWebController.

In TTWebController.m:118 I see that this is setting the toolbar's tintColor:

```
_toolbar.tintColor = TTSTYLEVAR(toolbarTintColor);
```

So I created my own stylesheet that subclasses TTDefaultStyleSheet and overrides toolbarTintColor

FooStyleSheet.h:

```
#import <Three20Style/Three20Style.h>
#import <Three20Style/TTStyleSheet.h>
#import <Three20Style/TTDefaultStyleSheet.h>

@interface FooStyleSheet : TTDefaultStyleSheet

@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIColor* toolbarTintColor;

@end
```

FooStyleSheet.m:

```
#import "FooStyleSheet.h"

@implementation RaptrStyleSheet

- (UIColor*)toolbarTintColor {
    return RGBCOLOR(0, 0, 0); // should override TTDefaultStyleSheet
}

@end
```

and in my application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: i set my default stylesheet

```
[TTStyleSheet setGlobalStyleSheet:[[[FooStyleSheet alloc] init] autorelease]];
```

but when I view the TTWebController, it doesn't inherit my tintColor. If I edit TTDefaultStyleSheet.m directly:

```
- (UIColor*)toolbarTintColor {
  return [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

it works as expected.

Is there something I am overlooking that is preventing my style to be picked up?

thanks,
-norm

Comment: Hi funkadelic, did you find an answer of your question?

Answer (score 0):

In your header file, the @property is unnecessary - does removing this solve your problem?